# Compute OEIS A005434

Tags: array, combinatorics, fastest-code

The task is to compute [OEIS A005434](https://oeis.org/A005434) as quickly as possible.

Consider a binary string `S` of length `n`.  Indexing from `1`, we can determine if `S[1..i+1]` matches `S[n-i..n]` exactly for all `i` in order from `0` to `n-1`.      For example,

```
S = 01010
```

gives

```
[Y, N, Y, N, Y].
```

This is because `0` matches `0`, `01` does not match `10`, `010` matches `010`, `0101` does not match `1010`  and finally `01010` matches itself.

Define `f(n)` to be the number of distinct arrays of `Y`s and `N`s one gets when iterating over all `2^n` different possible bit strings `S` of length `n`.

The observant will notice this question is a simpler variant of [another recent question of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124424/finding-approximate-correlations). However, I expect that clever tricks can make this much faster and easier.

### Task

For increasing `n` starting at `1`, your code should output `n, f(n)`.

### Example answers

For `n = 1..24`, the correct answers are:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13, 17, 21, 27, 30, 37, 47, 57, 62, 75, 87, 102, 116, 135, 155, 180, 194
```

### Scoring

Your code should iterate up from `n = 1` giving the answer for each `n` in turn. I will time the entire run, killing it after two  minutes.

Your score is the highest `n` you get to in that time.

In the case of a tie, the first answer wins.

### Where will my code be tested?

I will run your code under Virtualbox in a [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) guest VM (on my Windows 7 host).

My laptop has 8GB of RAM and an Intel i7 5600U@2.6 GHz (Broadwell) CPU with 2 cores and 4 threads. The instruction set includes SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA3 and TSX.

### Leading entries per language

- **n = 599** in **Rust** bu Anders Kaseorg.
- **n= 30** in **C** by Grimy. Parallel version gets to **32** when run natively  in cygwin.

Comment: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/SEQUENCES/autocorrelation-range.c (linked from the OEIS page) run with -O3 can calculate up to 100 in <.02 seconds on my machine

Comment: @rogaos Oh dear.  I should delete the question but it already has an answer.

Comment: I think it's still a cool problem – but maybe up to 1000 instead? Or ask answers to golf a sufficiently fast program

Comment: @rogaos I just removed the hard limit completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), n ≈ 660

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::iter::once;
use std::rc::Rc;

type Memo = HashMap<(u32, u32, Rc<Vec<u32>>), u64>;

fn f(memo: &mut Memo, mut n: u32, p: u32, mut s: Rc<Vec<u32>>) -> u64 {
    debug_assert!(p != 0);
    let d = n / p;
    debug_assert!(d >= 1);
    let r = n - p * if d >= 2 { d - 1 } else { 1 };

    let k = s.binary_search(&(n - r + 1)).unwrap_or_else(|i| i);
    for &i in &s[..k] {
        if i % p != 0 {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if d >= 3 {
        let o = n - (p + r);
        n = p + r;
        s = Rc::new(s[k..].iter().map(|i| i - o).collect());
    } else if n == p {
        return 1;
    } else if k != 0 {
        s = Rc::new(s[k..].to_vec());
    }

    let query = (n, p, s);
    if let Some(&c) = memo.get(&query) {
        return c;
    }
    let (n, p, s) = query;

    let t = Rc::new(s.iter().map(|i| i - p).collect::<Vec<_>>());
    let c = if d < 2 {
        (1..r + 1).map(|q| f(memo, r, q, t.clone())).sum()
    } else if r == p {
        (1..p + 1)
            .filter(|&q| p % q != 0 || q == p)
            .map(|q| f(memo, r, q, t.clone()))
            .sum()
    } else {
        let t = match t.binary_search(&p) {
            Ok(_) => t,
            Err(k) => {
                Rc::new(t[..k]
                            .iter()
                            .cloned()
                            .chain(once(p))
                            .chain(t[k..].iter().cloned())
                            .collect::<Vec<_>>())
            }
        };
        (1..t.first().unwrap() + 1)
            .filter(|&q| p % q != 0 || q == p)
            .map(|q| f(memo, r, q, t.clone()))
            .sum()
    };
    memo.insert((n, p, s), c);
    c
}

fn main() {
    let mut memo = HashMap::new();
    let s = Rc::new(Vec::new());
    for n in 1.. {
        println!("{} {}",
                 n,
                 (1..n + 1)
                     .map(|p| f(&mut memo, n, p, s.clone()))
                     .sum::<u64>());
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVVRb9owEH7nV1wrLXLW4JV22kOgeZu0l6pSJ@2lqlBqTIlIHGM7qyrgr4@dHROSwMbelgewznef7777zlaVNrtdpTloM4tjVuY5ZyYrhY7jb6le3KdyPGi2M8NVHJeC8ZZRsTh@ZOPBwLxLDve8KOEOfOyEVLc3EbifRzb5wdkE10kSou3L5wSD5gLmpMCgGIKiMi4@ArsScR0n/b@16bgLA8PEAsF6APjN@Ev1Ok215spcEAkXd3Adjt1Wzg3MMC8Bn0COT3jPILmDUctbOe8hSPgI2Rzc/g2scTGEEWyB50jA2i6xin3QEoM0fclEqt6nmqeKLUhALIyCK4QPaSXeVCqnpZpaALLJNpD5U@elgiCDTECgnyhdPvuy7IcZZPAB6ppadvspbiol4HrcWLeD@nfgQ13yt60wm2vpC0SirkCFh2iBG852MGk0PWKfBX8j@mlJ6TO1WiAhLVJZF4FIZUi9gEjo8TxPmAOiWthDDj7tUd9x2a/xxOGmnP7k7HDKoQOriqt3DCAClROB9h6Ia3e/lwUnAQvRwWqOvnJDAhcSHmfG9uB77AYTw11Qq/OmneQpcmRDThw7BU@TpCnAIjBEcL2aWJ01yZARpbV4arjVxg9MBCqCVQSGsrwUHLFCqquChD0@VZ94iygdYkdGdJ7lNu1NgEdIFNuqbsRmgysL0XM/m03X/Si1rhotf0Vq2AIRevMjw57gH5Zkij1IwEQd@1elyNJtdP3tt@@NcZN1tN1Jte7e331clbOzXos0E8RemESG/@RrOtO1P@Vc6AlhdSK2h6th3NGBwa4rjfPqLyYS/k9h1Lm5ycyEvZdJM3IRMD8rbLB1z0Zh6dpLw0rIPhBF5/mpW96asfZVglT5/db9K@z1i7y0FCRVJkwuLsjlegvr7WV03AtxwmbZFcdk9miSlqZgn3kEvtw/cNUhDbtt39DWJbjd7X6xeZ6@6t3w4Tc)

#### How it works

This is a memoized implementation of the recursive predicate Ξ given in Leo Guibas, [“Periods in strings”](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(81)90038-8) (1981).  The function `f(memo, n, p, s)` finds the number of correlations of length `n` with smallest period `p` and also each of the periods in the set `s`.

Comment: Makes you wonder if there is a faster solution to the other related problem. Very impressive!

Comment: Interestingly this is entirely memory limited. It speeds up to ~500 and then  suddenly slows down as it runs out of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple brute-force search, to get the challenge started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint16_t u16;
typedef uint64_t u64;

static u64 map[1<<16];

int main(void)
{
    for (u64 n = 1;; ++n) {
        u64 result = 1;
        u64 mask = (1ul << n) - 1;
        memset(map, 0, sizeof(map));

        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp for
        for (u64 x = 1ul << (n - 1); x < 1ul << n; ++x) {

            u64 r = 0;
            for (u64 i = 1; i < n; ++i)
                r |= (u64) (x >> i == (x & (mask >> i))) << i;
            if (!r)
                continue;

            u16 h = (u16) (r ^ r >> 13 ^ r >> 27);
            while (map[h] && map[h] != r)
                ++h;

            if (!map[h]) {
                #pragma omp critical
                if (!map[h]) {
                    map[h] = r;
                    ++result;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%ld\n", result);
    }
}
```

Compile with `clang -fopenmp -Weverything -O3 -march=native`. On my machine it reaches n=34 in 2 minutes.

EDIT: sprinkled some OMP directives for easy parallelism.

Comment: @Lembik Is existence of a good answer outside of SE grounds for deletion? Shouldn’t you wait for somebody (possibly the commenter) to submit this algorithm as an answer, and accept that answer?

Comment: You make a very good point

Comment: Sadly I can't really test your parallel code in virtualbox as I have a total of two cores on my CPU.

Comment: I ran it in cygwin and it got to 32.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, n≈427

Rewrite [@Anders Kaseorg's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127038/110802) in Python

[TIO Link](https://tio.run/##jVPRjpswEHz3V2xVVTI9LhdyL1V06Y8gdKJgehZgO/ai6r4@Xa8hkFSV4geQZ2dnZ722@8QPa15/OH@56NFZj/BLB9Wg6LwdobHDQBttTYA53KqungZsNXFmCPWohBjVaOG0jUttMBOBwLISggLQSZODyyFkRwG06hCUR@ngywn2GUMt0Q28vIDbMlr4eYIiMTwznsHBd6DAMxSgO2DGAdQQVCQysydmameXfu@D6lCGnPM9PC2SnfWgQRsI5bGvkre4SFfDN0j@VphdKJy8gX2qtBh4XUl2tkndPYHPrrghnKErwiekiWq3RvpjVTFFDaROWZS2qs/li5XR35mMqqySHJ4n5T8JmieAkxuUDFm22E9xqhzn@E@dCJZMmeVw8ew2nqv1LN7gsIo00co0yk76HM5UPOOkc0zytfmtZJHP48jWhvxdyw@pOFaJHhwN7sxnAsyKYot6UKvsfy4J5gt97qmnngZlJJWtTQtY9tWdwbgcXdgrcFuIj22nDV/o/kb@odaw3FcPdLcZFak2YjPFRoiAtcf3@GIpGH@7@JGZiNeyEH8@9KC2OE14k/IGxWF/BPgKfjJssUYYbUB6eaM2E6rUvPP09ONNS00tj54z3E1TJk09WadNNHG5/AU)

```python
import bisect
from collections import defaultdict
import time

memo = defaultdict(int)
s = []

def f(n, p, s):
    assert(p != 0)
    d = n // p
    assert(d >= 1)
    r = n - p * (d - 1 if d >= 2 else 1)

    k = bisect.bisect_left(s, n - r + 1)
    for i in s[:k]:
        if i % p != 0:
            return 0

    if d >= 3:
        o = n - (p + r)
        n = p + r
        s = [i - o for i in s[k:]]
    elif n == p:
        return 1
    elif k != 0:
        s = s[k:]

    query = (n, p, tuple(s))
    if query in memo:
        return memo[query]

    t = [i - p for i in s]
    if d < 2:
        c = sum(f(r, q, t) for q in range(1, r + 1))
    elif r == p:
        c = sum(f(r, q, t) for q in range(1, p + 1) if p % q != 0 or q == p)
    else:
        k = bisect.bisect_left(t, p)
        if k < len(t) and t[k] == p:
            pass
        else:
            t.insert(k, p)
        c = sum(f(r, q, t) for q in range(1, t[0] + 1) if p % q != 0 or q == p)
    memo[query] = c
    return c

start_time = time.time()
n = 1
while time.time() - start_time < 120:  # run for at most 2 minutes
    print(n, sum(f(n, p, s) for p in range(1, n + 1)))
    n += 1
```